# Integrals as vector spaces

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I saw an integral version of the Cauchy Schwartz inequality. Could someone please explain what is the vector space, the corresponding field and the inner product space here.

Comment: could you please show us this integral version you're talking about?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you mean the inequality
$$\left\vert\int_\Omega f\bar g\mathrm dV\right\vert^2\leq\int_\Omega\vert f\vert^2\mathrm d V\int_\Omega\vert g\vert^2\mathrm dV.$$

The space is $L^2(\Omega,\mathbb F)$, the space of square integrable functions $f:\Omega\longrightarrow\mathbb F$, where $\Omega$ is a measure space and $\mathbb F\in\{\mathbb R,\mathbb C\}$. This is a vector space over $\mathbb F$. A function is square integrable if
$$\Vert f\Vert_2^2:=\int_\Omega \vert f\vert^2\mathrm dV<\infty.$$
Such a vector space becomes an inner product space via the inner product
$$\langle f,g\rangle:=\int_\Omega f\bar g\mathrm d V,$$
where $\bar g$ is the complex conjugate of $g$. The norm induced by this inner product is exactly the norm $\Vert f\Vert_2$ from above.

As a side note: Technically speaking, what I described is $\mathcal L^2$. The space $L^2$, on which the above is a well-defined inner product, is the quotient space of $\mathcal L^2$ with respect to the relation defined as $f\sim g$ iff $f=g$ almost everywhere.